# Dropdown makes textbox appear and required, not required when not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have a select drop down with about 25 options certain choices that are picked will make another textbox field appear and be required. I tried making it grayed out and always there but since nothing was entered it was still required and would not process.

Now I have changed it to read-only and just wrote Not Required in the box since its filled out it would accept if its a required field.

But I really would like to learn how to make it just appear when that option is selected and once it appears make it required so the user can not go onto the next page until it is filled out.

(If you choose pickup or truck it is required)
So basically Dropdown makes textbox appear and required and not required when it is not showing

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/of1sdq11/

```js
 function GVW(){
   var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('vehiclebody');
   var textbox = document.getElementById('gvw');
   if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 0){
     textbox.value = "";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = false;
   } 
    else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 1) {
     textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = true;
   }
    else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 2) {
     textbox.value = "";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = false;
   }
    else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 3) {
     textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = true;
   } 
    else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 4) {
     textbox.value = "";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = false;
   } 
    else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 5) {
     textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";
   document.getElementById("gvw").readOnly = true;
   } 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required="yes" message="Please select body." size="1"  onChange="GVW();">
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="0">2Dr</option>
    <option value="1">Pickup</option>
    <option value="2">4dr</option>
    <option value="3">Truck</option>
    <option value="4">Convertible</option>
    <option value="5">Van</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()" message="Please enter gross vehicle weight." value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to make it so the textbox doesn't even show unless it is required.  I modified the code a bit so that you don't need the list of if statements.  By making an array that corresponds to the selectedIndex, you can just check the property!

Find the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/of1sdq11/19/

First, I made the textbox start hidden.  If the display is set to none, it will not be submitted with the form.  If display is anything other than none, it will display and submit with the form.  If you just wanted an invisible field that was always submitted, you would use visibility set to hidden instead!

```
<input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()" message="Please enter gross vehicle weight." value="" style="display:none;">
```

Then I modified your code to show the textbox if the properties match.  Now all you have to do is set whether required is true or false in the "is_required" variable to match the corresponding selectedIndex and it should work.

```
 function GVW(){
   var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('vehiclebody');
   var textbox = document.getElementById('gvw');
   // Array for storing whether the textbox is required
   var is_required = [false, true, false, true, false, true];

   // If dropdown1.selectedIndex is 0, it will pull the value from the 0 slot
   // of the is_required array
   if(is_required[dropdown1.selectedIndex]) {
       textbox.required = true;
       textbox.style.display = "inline-block";
   } else {
       textbox.value = "";
       textbox.required = false;
       textbox.style.display = "none";  
   }

 }
```

Now on whatever page you are submitting to, you can just check to see if the textbox even existed in the form submission, and if it did, get the data, otherwise skip it!

**jQuery Version With Modifications**

After further discussion with the OP, I rewrote this to work with all jQuery, along with adding the ability to hide a label in addition.  I thought that others may find it helpful, so I wanted to post it here.  Find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/of1sdq11/26/

**The HTML**

```
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required="yes" message="Please select body." size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="0">2Dr</option>
    <option value="1">Pickup</option>
    <option value="2">4dr</option>
    <option value="3">Truck</option>
    <option value="4">Convertible</option>
    <option value="5">Van</option>
</select>

<div style="display:inline;">
    <label for="gvw" style="display:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gross Vehicle Weight:*</label> 
    <input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()" message="Please enter gross vehicle weight." value="" style="display:none;">
    <p style="display:none;">*Gross Vehicle Weight is required for heavy trucks over 5000 lbs. Visit our website for more information.&nbsp;<a href="http://www.taxcollector.com/services_vehicle_heavy_truck.asp" target="_blank">Heavy Truck Information and Fee Schedule based on GVW</a> </p>
</div>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('#vehiclebody').change(function() {
       var selected_index = $(this).find(":selected").index();
       var textbox = $('#gvw');
       var label = textbox.siblings('label');
       var paragraph = textbox.siblings('p');
       // Array for storing whether the textbox is required
       var is_required = [false, true, false, true, false, true];

       // If dropdown1.selectedIndex is 0, it will pull the value from the 0 slot
       // of the is_required array
       if(is_required[selected_index]) {
           textbox.attr("required", "true");
           textbox.show();
           label.show();
           paragraph.show();
       } else {
           textbox.val("");
           textbox.attr("required", "false");
           textbox.hide();
           label.hide();
           paragraph.hide();
       }
    });

 });
```

Comment: This still makes the box required when if its not

Comment: if they chose an option and it disappears when submitting it is saying its still required

Comment: Updating my code now to try something else!  Please let me know if it works for you now!

Comment: Is it possible to hide the label also? It only hides the textbox can the label be hidden as well?

Comment: Absolutely, though I am not sure what you are referring to when you say "label".  I take label to mean text before the textbox, but I don't see any text before the box!  You would just get the label element the same way you get the textbox and dropdownbox1, and then set display:none to that variable in the same code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63604/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-joshwa-i-am).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need. Check this fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/of1sdq11/15/

```
<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required="yes" message="Please select body." size="1"  onChange="GVW();">
<option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
<option value="0">2Dr</option>
<option value="1">Pickup</option>
<option value="2">4dr</option>
<option value="3">Truck</option>
<option value="4">Convertible</option>
<option value="5">Van</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="gvw" id="gvw" onfocus="this.select()" message="Please enter gross vehicle weight." value="" hidden>
```

.

```
 function GVW(){
   var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('vehiclebody');
   var textbox = document.getElementById('gvw');
   if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 0){
     textbox.value = "";
       document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = false;
      document.getElementById("gvw").required = "yes";
   } 
   else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 1) {
   textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";

    document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("gvw").required = "no";
 }
 else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 2) {
    textbox.value = "";
    document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = false;
     document.getElementById("gvw").required = "yes";
 }
 else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 3) {
    textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";

    document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("gvw").required = "no";
 } 
 else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 4) {
     textbox.value = "";
     document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = false;
     document.getElementById("gvw").required = "yes";
 } 
 else if(dropdown1.selectedIndex == 5) {
     textbox.value = "NOT REQUIRED";

     document.getElementById("gvw").hidden = true;
     document.getElementById("gvw").required = "no";
 } 
}
```

Comment: This will not fix it the field is still required no matter what. If you delete the "Not Required" and submit the box is still required.